# multiple axes in one figure, can we specify handle axes in text function matlab?

Tags: matlab

i have a problem with my function text in matlab

```
function plot_circles(ax)
hold on
elev=[0 15 30 45 60 90];
elev=elev*pi./180;
R=1;
teta=0:pi/60:2*pi;
for i=1:length(elev)
   plot(ax,R*sin(elev(i))*cos(teta),R*sin(elev(i))*sin(teta),'k.');
   text(R*sin(elev(i))*cos(pi/2),R*sin(elev(i))*sin(pi/2)+0.05,num2str(elev(i)*180/pi));
end
```

it's work good but for my work, i will create many axes in one figure

```
h_fig=figure('Color',[1 1 1]);
ax1=axes('Position',[0.05 0.1 0.4 0.8]);axis off
ax2=axes('Position',[0.5 0.6 0.45 0.3]);axis off
ax3=axes('Position',[0.5 0.05 0.4 0.3]);axis off
plot_circles(ax1);
plot_circles(ax2);
plot_circles(ax3);
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the axis in a call to `text` using the `parent` [property value pair](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/text_props.html). Replacing the line

```
text(R*sin(elev(i))*cos(pi/2),R*sin(elev(i))*sin(pi/2)+0.05,num2str(elev(i)*180/pi));
```

with

```
text(R*sin(elev(i))*cos(pi/2),R*sin(elev(i))*sin(pi/2)+0.05,num2str(elev(i)*180/pi),...
    'parent',ax);
```

will add the text to the required axis!

**Extra note:**  `hold on` in the function will be applied to the current axis not `ax` replacing with `hold(ax,'on')` will apply hold to the axis `ax`

### Output

With both changes made here is the output:

[image]